# Find out approximate "ownership" of source files in git

Tags: git, gitlab

I have some refactoring chores in a large collaborative project

I found how I can list files I added [here](https://superuser.com/questions/309630/find-all-files-added-by-git-user)

I'd find it useful to list all files I:

1. did an minimum of X changes to
2. or is otherwise indicative of me having done major work to the file

Is there a command or tool that can achieve this?

Note: git is also hosted on Gitlab 9.2

Comment: You would have to write such a tool yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This commands gives you a list of files with creators:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -I{} -n1 sh -c "git log --reverse --format='%cN' '{}' | head -n1 | xargs -I[] echo '[];{}'" | grep -E "^your name;"
```

- `git ls-files -z` - list of files separated by `\0`
- `git log --reverse --format='%cN' '{}' | head -n1` - provides name of creator of the file
- `xargs -I[] echo '[];{}'` - polish output into `creator;filename`
- `grep -E "^your name;"` - reduce output only to your files; do not forget modify it or you will get empty results.

For listing files with more than `N` changes you can use following commands:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -I{} -n1 sh -c "git log --numstat --format='%cN' '{}' | sed -E -n -e '1h;3{s/\s+/;/g;H;x;s/\n/;/;p}'" | grep -E "^your name;" | awk -v limit=10 -F';' '{files[$4] += $2 + $3} END {for(file in files) if(files[file] > limit){print file, files[file]}}'
```

- `git ls-files -z` - list of files separated by `\0`
- `git log --numstat --format='%cN' '{}'` - print commiter name for concrete commit and number of changes (number of new lines in the file and number of deleted lines)
- `sed -E -n -e '1h;3{s/\s+/;/g;H;x;s/\n/;/;p}'` - polish output into `commiter;new lines;deleted lines;filename`
- `grep -E "^your name;"` - reduce output only to your files; do not forget modify it or you will get empty results.
- `awk -v limit=10 -F';' '{files[$4] += $2 + $3} END {for(file in files) if(files[file] > limit){print file, files[file]}}'` - print only files with more than `10` changes. The changes are calculated as sum of new lines and deleted lines. If you want change limit for printing files just change the `-v limit=10` to your number.

I hope that is what you want.